# Match all text between two delimiters, add a string, and indent

Tags: python

I have a series of strings like so:

```
*question: Question 1 
    *shuffle
    Answer 1
    Answer 2
    *save: q1
    *throwaway  
>> q1_answer = "Answer 1"

*question: Question 2 
    *shuffle
    Answer 1
    Answer 2
    Answer 3
    *save: q2
    *throwaway  
>> q2_answer = "Answer 2"
```

I need to match the text between the `*question` line and the `>>` line, indent that entire text block, and add the term `*group` before it

For example:

```
*group
    *question: Question 1 
        *shuffle
        Answer 1
        Answer 2
        *save: q1
        *throwaway  
    >> q1_answer = "Answer 1"

*group  
    *question: Question 2 
        *shuffle
        Answer 1
        Answer 2
        Answer 3
        *save: q2
        *throwaway  
    >> q2_answer = "Answer 2"
```

I can match the `question` line like so:

```
rx = re.compile(r'(\*question.+)', re.M)
```

I can match the `>>` line like so:

```
rx2 = re.compile(r'(\>.+)', re.M)
```

But I'm not sure how to match all the content between those two delimiters and tab it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub()`. The replacement can be a function that computes the new string, so it can add the tabs.

```
new_text = re.sub(r'\*question.+?>>', 
        lambda m: '*group\n\t' + m.group(0).replace('\n', '\n\t'), 
        text, 
        flags=re.DOTALL)
```

[DEMO](http://new_text%20=%20re.sub(r'%5C*question.+?%3E%3E',%20lambda%20m:%20'*group%5Cn%5Ct'%20%20%20m.group(0).replace('%5Cn',%20'%5Cn%5Ct'),%20text,%20flags=re.DOTALL))